# How to show Wordpress sub-menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have a page "About us" which has two child pages. In my WP template functions.php I output the title of the page using:

```
if (is_page() && !is_front_page()) { ?>
   <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
}
```

I want to list the subpages names and links next to the title and I have no idea where to start.

I would be gratefull if you could point me in the right direction!

/Ismail

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

```
        <?php
          if($post->post_parent)
          $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
          else
          $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
          if ($children) {
          $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);?>
          <span class="entry-title">/</span>
          <ul class="custom-sub-menu">
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>"><?php echo $parent_title;?></a></li>
          <?php echo $children; ?>
        <?php } ?>
          </ul>
```